# R non-linear model fitting using fitModel function

Tags: r, model, non-linear-regression

I want to fit a non-linear model to a real data.

The real data consists of 2 known *numerical vectors* ; thickness as 'x' and fh as 'y'

```
thickness=seq(0.15,2.00,by=0.05)

fh = c(5.17641, 4.20461, 3.31091, 2.60899, 2.23541, 1.97771, 1.88141, 1.62821, 1.50138, 1.51075, 1.40850, 1.26222, 1.09432, 1.13202, 1.12918, 1.10355, 1.11867, 1.09740,1.08324, 1.05687, 1.19422, 1.22984, 1.34516, 1.19713,1.25398 ,1.29885, 1.33658, 1.31166, 1.40332, 1.39550,1.37855, 1.41491, 1.59549, 1.56027, 1.63925, 1.72440, 1.74192, 1.82049)
plot(thickness,fh)
```

This is apparently non-linear. So, I am trying to fit this model as a non-linear function of

```
y= x*2/3+(2+2*a)/(3*x)
```

Variable `a` is an unknown constant and I am trying to find the best constant `a` that minimizes the sum of square of error between the regression line and the real data.

I first used a function `fitModel` that I found on a YouTube video, [Fitting Functions to Data in R](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gMSGml7Hcec).

```
 library(TIMP)
 f=fitModel(fh~thickness^2/3+(2+2*A)/(3*thickness)) #it finds the coefficient 'A'
coef(f) # to represent just the coefficient
```

However, there's an error

> Error in modelspec[[datasetind[i]]] : subscript out of bounds

So, as an alternative, want to find a plot of 'a' and 'the Sum of Squares of Error'. This time, I have such a hard time finding 'a' and plotting this graph. By manual work, I figured out the value 'a' is somewhere near 0.2 but this is not a precise value.

It would be helpful if someone could manifest either:

1. Why the `fitModel` function didn't work or
2. How to find the value `a` and plot the graph.

Comment: The reason you are not getting any response is that people are seeing a link to a video file and don't fell like going out to view it to replicate your setup efforts. You should instead start out with a call to install.packages and library and then use the specialized function in that non-standard package to load the data. You may need touse a `dput` output of your data. Then and only then will potential responders be in a position to help with what will then be a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

You could try this instead:

```
yf = function(a,xv) xv*(2/3)+(2+2*a)/(3*xv)
yf(2,thickness)
f <- function (a,y, xv) sum((y - yf(a,xv))^2)
f(2,fh,thickness)
xmin <- optimize(f, c(0, 10), tol = 0.0001, y=fh,xv=thickness)
xmin
plot(thickness,fh)
lines(thickness,yf(xmin$minimum,thickness),col=3)
```

[image]